# Artifactory with S3 replication - will I get reference to the "nearest" copy?

Tags: amazon-s3, artifactory

We're looking at using Artifactory with S3 storage - along with EC2 instances to provide elastic infrastructure for compile (CI/CD).  We have distributed development sites around the globe that need to share components and we were thinking that it would be "more efficient" to use S3 replication into each AWS geo area.

Will Artifactory present the "nearest" copy from S3 automatically -or- is Artifactory replication the only way to get that to work?

We'd like to have minimal added maintenance (e.g. not have to support multiple Artifactory instances) as well as cost (e.g. not have to pay to store multiple copies of the components around the globe).

Happy to entertain a "better design"!

Comment: Note that S3 replication means paying to store copies.

Comment: Not sure how this will work for you, or am I missing something. If you have several development centers how will they get the binaries directly from S3? Let's bear in mind that in order to fetch an Artifact you need to go to Artifactory, get the response and only then Artifactory will take the binary, which is stored by the checksum and serve it to the user. Meaning that either way the traffic is going via the Artifactory cluster and not directly fffrom the storage backend. What am I missing?

Comment: Fair points - both - I was under the (mistaken?) impression that the S3 replica was "lower cost" than 2 separate S3 "buckets" ... I think at one time it was ... but the pricing model may have changed since I last dug into it.  As to Ariel's point - yeah - I was actually hoping for a bit of magic in the chain.  That is, Artifactory would "know" about the replica(s), and serve up a reference to the one closest to the site that made the request.  Clearly just a dream <grin>.